# Django - Admin list_filter only for superuser?

Tags: django, django-admin-filters

Is it possible to show list_filter only for superuser?

Answer (score 6):

#### [Override changelist view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.changelist_view)

Store a copy of the original list filter so that you can dynamically set the attribute per-request. Check if the user is a superuser, and set the list filter property or not.

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = ('id',)
    _list_filter = list_filter
    # must store list filter reference somewhere

    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):    
        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            self.list_filter = None
        else:
            self.list_filter = self._list_filter
        return super(MyAdmin, self).changelist_view(request, extra_context)
```

Answer (score 4):

Since Django 1.5, you can use [ModelAdmin.get_list_filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_list_filter):

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_list_filter(self, request):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return ['field']
        else:
            return []
```